# Jquery associate click event to row of dynamic table in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've Add the event click to my dynamic table but it doesnt work.

```
$("#gridVille").append('<table id="idTableVille" class="table table-striped table-hover">');
        $("#idTableVille").append('<thead>');
        $("#idTableVille thead").append('<tr><th>Code commune</th><th>Libellé</th></tr>');
        $("#idTableVille").append('</thead>');

        $("#idTableVille").append('<tbody>');
        for (i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
            $("#idTableVille tbody").append('<tr id="' +liste[i].id+ '">');
            $('#idTableVille tbody').append('<td scope="row" class="idCommune">' + liste[i].id+ '</td>');
            $('#idTableVille tbody').append('<td class="libelleCommune">' + liste[i].libelle+ '</td>');
            $("#idTableVille tbody").append('</tr>');
        }
        $("#idTableVille").append('</tbody>');
        $("#gridVille").append('</table>');

$('#idTableVille tr').click(function () {
 var id = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
 var libelle = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
 alert(id + ' ' + libelle);
});
```

this code is added after populating the table.

The scenario is :

1. I Open the modal (bootstrap modal)
2. I populate the table
3. I click to any row of table for getting the values of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the `<tr>` element to the `<tbody>` and then also appending every `<td>` to the `<tbody>` instead of the newly generated row, so instead of a regular table structure:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="something">
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Hello!</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You are getting this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="something"></tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Hello!</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If you change the code inside the for loop it should get fixed:

```
for (i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
      $("#idTableVille tbody").append('<tr id="' +liste[i].id+ '">');
      $('#idTableVille tbody tr#' + liste[i].id).append('<td scope="row" class="idCommune">' + liste[i].id+ '</td>');
      $('#idTableVille tbody tr#' + liste[i].id).append('<td class="libelleCommune">' + liste[i].libelle+ '</td>');
}
```

As you can see, I'm appending the  elements to the newly created row, using the id to select it.

You can see it working here:

https://jsbin.com/yojajisuca/edit?html,js,output